# ModuleName-Swift.h generated with missing methods

Tags: xcode, swift

I have the following Swift class

```
public class Model :   NSObject
{
    override init()
    { (...) }

    class func  fileListHasBeenUpdatedEvent() -> String
    { (...) }

    func    fileExtensions() -> [String]
    { (...) }

    func    filesWithExtension(ext : String) -> [ModelFile]
    { (...) }

    func addFilesWithThoseURLs(urlList:[NSURL])
    { (...) }
    }

    func fileListHasBeenUpdated(modelElement : EasyModelElementProtocol)
    { (...) }
}
```

and the generated ModuleName-Swift.h looks like

```
@interface Model : NSObject
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
+ (NSString * __nonnull)fileListHasBeenUpdatedEvent;
- (NSArray<NSString *> * __nonnull)fileExtensions;
- (void)addFilesWithThoseURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> * __nonnull)urlList;
@end
```

So I am clearly missing the filesWithExtension: and fileListHasBeenUpdated:. I have cleaned the Derived data several times and rebuilt in many ways...

Is this a known XCode bug ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Is ModelFile present in the generated file, thus representable in ObjC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess but I imagine `EasyModelElementProtocol` and `ModelFile` are objects that can't be represented in Objective C.

`EasyModelElementProtocol` needs to conform to the `NSObject` and i'm guessing that `ModelFile` might be either a struct or a Class that doesn't inherit from `NSObject`

IIRC you should be able to test this by marking the functions as `@objc` and the compiler should inform you about exactly why it can't be represented in Objective C